# Android Studio stucks on Resolving Dependencies in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I am working on a project which needs some dependencies that i added in pubspec.yaml

```
  dependencies:

  flutter:

    sdk: flutter

  google_sign_in: "^0.3.1"

  firebase_auth: "^0.2.3"


  http: "^0.11.3+16"

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0

  flutter_markdown: "^0.1.5"

  url_launcher: "^3.0.1"

  share: "^0.4.0"
```

when i click on Packages Get in pubspec.yaml it shows this

```
C:\Flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages get

Running "flutter packages get" in list_drag_drop...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And when i Click on Get Dependencies in pubspec.yaml it shows this

```
Working dir: D:\Flutter proj downloaded\list_drag_drop

C:\Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat get

Resolving dependencies...

Because share 0.4.0 requires the Flutter SDK and no versions of share match>0.4.0 <0.5.0, share ^0.4.0 is forbidden.
```

So, because `list_drag_drop` depends on share ^0.4.0, version solving failed.

Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`.
Process finished with exit code 1

And when I Run my Project it stucks on Resolving Dependencies. 
Please someone help , i have googled it but cannot resolve issue . i have flutter and dart plugin installed.

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Can you please add the output of `flutter doctor`?

Comment: You can try to `flutter clean`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Actually, to me it seems like `flutter packages get` is working fine here, so no need to worry.